Placement issue of joystick button in flutter
I just wrote a Flutter joystick widget, but I am currently facing two issues:
The innermost (smallest) joystick is not centered.
When I tap on the button initially, the movement is towards the top right first before I try to drag it to the right.
For now, I am hardcoding the inner joystick's position to center like this:
Positioned(
            top: joystickInnerPosition.dy - innerCircleSize / 6,
            left: joystickInnerPosition.dx - innerCircleSize / 6,


I dont want to hard code the position but have failed to get it mathematically.
You can try this in  DART PAD
